# Can you call ExpressJS hosted REST APIs over plain HTTP from a secured SSL enabled ReactJs app?

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, ssl

ok, my web app is in ReactJS and my REST APIs are running under ExpressJS. In the development environment on my Mac, I don't have SSL setup for anything so, my site runs on say http://localhost:3000 and my ExpressJs server runs on another port say 8000. Both of them communicates over HTTP and it works fine.

Now in UAT I've Nginx as a reverse proxy to my ReactJS App. Nginx has SSL cert installed for my site and I can access my site over HTTPs. My APIs runs on a different host using ExpressJs over plain HTTP i.e. no SSL setup.

Now, when my ReactJS app tries to make web service calls to consume REST APIs from my Express server, I get errors regarding mix bag of request i.e. my site is on HTTPS but tries to talk to the API server over plain HTTP. see below ...

```
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<host>/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://<apihost>/api/Security/Users'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Is there any way to override this without making ExpressJS APIs HTTPS enabled? If the answer is NO, how to setup ExpressJS to use HTTPS i.e. do people install Nginx as a reverse proxy and have the cert configured in Nginx. Just like what I did for my React app. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"Is there any way to override this without making ExpressJS APIs HTTPS enabled?"* - No. *"do people install Nginx as a reverse proxy and have the cert configured in Nginx. Just like what I did for my React app"* - Yes.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Will follow what Krisha has mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we have to use Nginx as reverse proxy for communication between frontend(https) and backend(https).
I have my ReactJs app running as http with Nginx and certificate configured.
I referred this link -
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04 to deploy ReactJs with Nginx and certificates.
In the folder /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, I have 2 files - a.docis.live and default

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
# Default server configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 80 ;

#   listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

#   root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

#   server_name _;

#   location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
#       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#       include uwsgi_params;
 #       uwsgi_pass unix:/root/backendOne/pyflaskone/myproject.sock;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

#}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /root/frontEndOne/pyflaskone/FRONT/late-checker/build;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name allspice.docis.live; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#        include uwsgi_params;
 
#       uwsgi_pass unix:/root/backendOne/pyflaskone/myproject.sock;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}


#    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/allspice.docis.live/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/allspice.docis.live/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = allspice.docis.live) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /root/frontEndOne/pyflaskone/FRONT/late-checker/build;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name allspice.docis.live; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #   include uwsgi_params;
       # uwsgi_pass unix:/root/backendOne/pyflaskone/myproject.sock;
#   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}


}
```

Here, I have my build for the late-checker app at this location /root/frontEndOne/pyflaskone/FRONT/late-checker/build

I also have Flask app running as http with Nginx and certificate configured.
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/a.docis.live

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

      #  root /root/frontEndOne/pyflaskone/FRONT/late-checker/build;
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        
        server_name allspice-api.docis.live;

        location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/root/backendOne/pyflaskone/myproject.sock;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

# listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/allspice-api.docis.live/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/allspice-api.docis.live/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Both are running as http on the local system and on the server. We just added certificates for running the apps with https prefix.

Credits: Suhail for Nginx and certificates configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Krishna so, I also followed the DigitalOcean guide for setting up my React front-end with SSL and that bit is working fine. My ExpressJs based APIs are on a different server and currently running using ExpressJs without any reverse proxy. Based on your answer I guess I have to install\setup nginx on the API server with my API web app being configured as SSL app.

Comment: Thanks Krishna and Steffen. Finally managed to get this working. I pretty much followed Krishna's guidelines with couple of exceptions as mine is ExpressJs. Below is my ssl.conf.  my expressjs server runs on port 8000.  
  
    location /  {
  
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000;  
  
     }
  
}